# Unable to mock kafka producer method in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mocking

I have a fairly simple code that I want to test. In an event that a process is unable to extract any information from an event, it should generate a kafka message. I want to test this situation by mocking the Kafka producer, and see how many times it is called.

```py
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import os

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': os.getenv("KAFKA_HOST")})
    
    def my_method(self, value):
        if value <= 0:
            self.producer.produce("TOPIC", {"value": value})

    def process(self, target):
        ... # some magic
        my_method(value)
```

Now I want to create a test where I can count the number of times the `produce` method has been called.

```py
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.clazz = MyClass()

    @unittest.mock.patch("my.path.to.mymodule.Producer.produce")
    def test_my_class_produces_kafka_msg(self, mock_produce):
        self.clazz.process("dummy")
        assert mock_produce.call_count == 1
```

This fails with the following message:
`TypeError: cannot set 'produce' attribute of immutable type 'cimpl.Producer'`

If I understand it correctly, it might be that the method is immutable. Which would mean I need to find a different approach. Is there a way to get around this, or is the better option to another method as a wrapper to the call to the kafka producer, and instead mock that one?